# Managing a drive - searching for files that are rarely in use (so I can delete them for space)

Tags: windows-7

I have a small server that is starting to get very full.

I would like to delete all old files that haven't been opened or modified in a long time.

Is there a way to search the entire drive by date opened - and the order form last to most recently opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely enough I'm just running a project to tidy up my companies old/historical data.

I'm using a powershell script that I wrote as below which outputs a CSV file for all files it comes across. I then use Excel to sort the data for whichever column is most useful for me.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\*path* -Recurse | Select-Object Name, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, Directory,  @{Name="Kbytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1Kb}} | Export-CSV xxxxxxx.csv
```

You can copy the above then paste in notepad, change the path to where your files are saved (locally is best although mapped drive would work) then save as "filename.ps1"

If you run in to any errors trying to run the powershell script let me know and I can advise accordingly.

Comment: I'd suggest just dropping this on the PowerShell console, instead of running it as a PS1. Saves the hassle of having to work around ExecutionPolicy and such. I like the addition of `Export-CSV`!

Comment: Nice job on the calculated value for Kbytes, too. I didn't realize you could do that.

Comment: @Iszi I think you're right about ExecutionPolicy - how can I drop straight into powershell? drag and drop the txt file?

Comment: @RubenBaden Copy/paste.

Comment: @Iszi when I run the script the pathing looks wrong. Powershell is looking at my local drive - I want to apply this script to a folder in a file server.

Comment: Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @RubenBaden Change `C:\*path*` to the network path you want searched. Example: `\\FileServer\ShareName`.

Comment: Thanks. I had put the address without \\ and it was looking for the location within my C: haha. Novice mistake! thanks again. On a side note do you know what \\ means? Is it root?

Comment: Also - when / how do I know when it's finished?

Comment: @RubenBaden ``\\`` is just a UNC path designator to tell the system you're specifying a resource on the network instead of locally. As far as when it's finished, you'll know when it produces output and/or returns you to the command prompt. If output has been redirected to a file, you won't see it on-screen. After the command prompt re-appears, just open the output file.

Comment: Thanks Iszi I normally don't log on at night (in UK) glad you got this working if you have any questions I'll be back on tomorrow to help out!

Comment: PowerShell sits there and blinks for a while (giving me the impression that its working). About 10 minutes later it stops and goes to the next PS input line. But I dont see a file open or save anywhere. Is it set to save in a specific loc?

Comment: @RubenBaden If you ran the command *exactly* as-is in the answer, and *only* changed `C:\*path*`, you'll find the output in a file called "xxxxxxx.csv" within the current working directory.

Comment: "Current working directory" being the network resource location? Or on my local machine?

Comment: I ask because I search for xxxxxxx.csv and on my file server. I haven't found it on either ):

Comment: @RubenBaden No it will be in directory of which the powershell script is ran.. either that or before the xxxxx.csv put a path such as c:\temp\xxxxxx.csv and it will be in there :)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem \ -Recurse | Sort-Object LastAccessTime | Select-Object FullName, LastAccessTime
```

This will find all files and folders on the current drive, sort them in ascending order by the last time they were accessed, and show their full path and last access time.

This will probably take awhile, especially on system drives or other drives with a large number of files and/or folders. However, you should *not* use this criteria alone when choosing to clean up files on a system drive or in an area where program files or data are stored - you could seriously break things if you do. Only use this for user data like documents, pictures, videos, etc.

PowerShell gives you a lot more options for working with the data, too. As @CharlesH has covered in his script, you can dump the output into a CSV file instead of just leaving it at the console. You can also do some filtering according to file size and other properties, or format the data to show more or less data and display it in a way more friendly to you.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use TCC from http://jpsoft.com/all-downloads/downloads.html (the LE version is free). This is a much-upgraded version of CMD, which allows you to both order and select by each of the file dates, eg:

```
dir /t:a /od                         - lists files in access time order;
dir /[da1980-1-1,2008-12-31]         - selects files not accessed since 2008;
del * /s /[da1980-1-1,2008-12-31] /n - shows deletable files not accessed since 2008;
del * /s /[da1980-1-1,2008-12-31]    - deletes files not accessed since 2008.
```

The range selection can also be used with `copy` and `move` commands, if you prefer to archive files instead of deleting them.

If (like me) you find PowerShell a bit daunting, you may prefer this.

Comment: 1. `Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object LastAccessTime`, 2. `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime.Year -le 2008}`, 3. `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime.Year -le 2008} | Remove-Item -WhatIf`, 4. `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime.Year -le 2008} | Remove-Item`. Given that PowerShell is 100% free, comes with Windows 7+, has commands and parameters that are generally much more human-readable and human-parseable than the syntax in this answer, *and* has a built-in help system plus gobs of online community support, I'm not sure how it's more "daunting" than TCC.

Comment: @Iszi - I don't dispute anything you say, though my commands will be familiar and readable to people who know CMD. I discovered TCC and its predecessors 4DOS and 4NT long before PowerShell was around. I had been accustomed to Unix shells and TCC & co provided a lot of the capability missing from CMD. I am sure PowerShell is no more difficult to learn than the Unix shells, but TCC is so familiar and powerful that I have never needed to learn it, though I am sure I shall grasp that nettle if I find myself limited by TCC. Except that there are some Windows implementations of Korn shell ... !

Comment: I get that `DIR /T:A /OD` might be familiar to CMD users, but I don't see how the `DIR` syntax, or the `DIR` filtering syntax should be. `DEL /S` in CMD does something *completely* different, and neither `DIR` nor `DEL` have any native filtering functionality similar to what is used here that I'm aware of or able to find.

Comment: If you're simply talking about similarity in command name alone, PowerShell has built-in aliases to re-direct many common CMD commands to the new PowerShell alternatives. (Example: `dir` calls `Get-ChildItem`.) PowerShell can also make direct use of most other native CMD commands, and many external commands, without any special accommodations needed.

Comment: @Iszi - The filtering is a TCC extension, which is the whole point; and `DEL /S` does the same in TCC as in CMD (delete from current directory and subdirectories). I must emphasise that I wasn't trying to undermine your answer in any way, but merely trying to offer an alternative which may be useful to people who have related problems and cannot use PowerShell (eg on earlier Windows).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion in `DEL /S`. I must have been reading about the same switch in a different section of the TCC docs or something. As for PowerShell, you've got to go back to Windows 2000/Me before you find an OS it can't run on. (And TCC can't go that far back either, though its predecessors may.) XP/2003 can't get the latest and greatest, and some of the newer modules aren't available below the latest Windows versions even with the same PowerShell version installed, but they can all still go up to at least PowerShell 2.0 which generally covers all the essentials.